# composer autoload files and variables

Tags: composer-php, autoload

I'm creating a class that gets a random string from an array. The data will not change enough to make using a database worth it, but there are a few hundred entries so I don't really want to put the entire thing, into the class I'm creating.

Is there a way I can use composers autoload files to create a new php file, dump the array in and use it where ever I like? I've read up and to do that you apparently need to use the globals keyword which I'd rather not do.

Am I thinking too much about this? Would you just add the array to the class, or do a require etc, the functionality of the class itself is tiny.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have these strings as text file. If its composer package, you can use [composer scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) and generate php file from this text file during installation.

Then you can have one class with your functionality and second class containing array of items only.

Items class generation can look like (not tested):

```
<?php
    ...
    $items = file_get_contents('items.txt');

    $fileContent = '<?php
    namespace Your\Namspace;
    class Items {
        public function getItems() {
            return [
                \'' . implode("',\n\t\t\t'", array_filter(explode("\n", $items))) . '\'
            ];
        }
    }';

    file_put_contents('Items.php', $fileContent);
```